# Load Ringtone into Mediaplayer from SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, uri

I'm afraid I have some sort of fundamental misunderstanding of how URI works here.  I am trying to save this alarm tone to my SharedPreferences file and then restore it in the same way.

I believe the problem is how I'm parsing the Uri, I'm not particularly aware of how URI would be retrieved

I have tried storing the following into my sharedpreferences.

```
//the displayed name of the ringtone
RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri).getTitle(this)
```

and

```
data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI)
```

The string of each restores properly, but I'm not aware of the actual key I need to parse to retrieve the alarm tone that I'm looking for.

Getting preferences as follows

```
/** Restore alarm tone and update UI */
        if (mSettings.contains(ALARM_TONE)){
            alarmTone = mSettings.getString(ALARM_TONE, null);
            if (alarmTone != null) {

                uri = Uri.parse(alarmTone);
                TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmTone);
                t.setText(RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri).getTitle(this));

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found uses `Uri.toString()` to save the Uri to preferences. Loading the ringtone back using `Uri.parse(preferenceString)`

onActivityresult, I immediately save the uri string to my preferences

```
    /** For selecting an alarmtone */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case ALARM_URI:
                    uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
                    TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmTone);
                    mTextView.setText(RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri).getTitle(this));

                    mp = new MediaPlayer();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);

                    mp.setLooping(true);

                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(ALARM_TONE, uri.toString());
                    editor.commit();

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Load the URI on start here

```
       if (mSettings.contains(ALARM_TONE)){
            alarmTone = mSettings.getString(ALARM_TONE, null);
            if (alarmTone != null) {
                uri = Uri.parse(alarmTone);
                //update textview to loaded alarm tone
                TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmTone);
                t.setText(RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri).getTitle(this));

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            }
        }
```